# Error when trying to move data from on-prem SQL database to Azure Delta lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, delta-lake

I am trying to move large amounts of reference data from on-prem SQL server to Delta lake to be used in databricks processing. To move this data, I am trying use Azure Data Factory via simple Copy data activity. but as soon as I start the pipeline I get the below error.  I googled this error but could not find any matches.

Note that sink delta table is not present in the delta lake ? does this error mean that I have create tables manually before moving data to delta lake ?

*Operation on target Copy data1 failed: ErrorCode=AzureDatabricksTableIsNotDeltaFormat,The table `benefit` is not delta format.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this using data flow rather than copy tasks.